# Stickers are disappearing from WhatsApp when I remove sticker app from background

Tags: android

When I was adding stickers in WhatsApp, stickers are added but if I remove stickers app from recent apps stickers are automatically getting disappeared from WhatsApp.

I have found this type of error:-
[This message was display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdnzI.jpg)

and

When I click on Settings, it redirect me on app info where I have already turned off battery saver mode but sticker are disappeared.

```
intent.setAction("com.whatsapp.intent.action.ENABLE_STICKER_PACK");
intent.putExtra(StickerPackDetailsActivity.EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_ID, identifier);
intent.putExtra(StickerPackDetailsActivity.EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_AUTHORITY, BuildConfig.CONTENT_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY);
intent.putExtra(StickerPackDetailsActivity.EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_NAME, stickerPackName);
return intent;
```

Now, when I remove App from Recent then Pack Name, Id and TrayImage are remaining but StickerList are disappear from pack.

I expect that after removing sticker app from background sticker should appear in whats app